# Problem with Jenkins and Mercurial repository

Tags: jenkins, mercurial

I have Jenkins installed on an ubuntu distribution. From Jenkins I need to be able to access a remote Mercurial repository via ssh and that, every time a commit is performed in this repository, I am notified by mail and/or slack that everything went well. First of all I have installed the Mercurial plugin in Jenkins, another plugin to manage mails and another one to manage slack. I have a public access key to access the repository. Actually from the ubuntu terminal I have no problem to clone this remote repository. I have the .rsa files in the corresponding .ssh folder with permissions for my user. The problem is that I don't really know how to configure Jenkins to perform this global action. The Error I have at the moment is the following:

```
Started by user XXXXX@DESKTOP-XXXXX
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TestRepo
$ hg --config ******** clone --rev default --noupdate "hg clone ssh://mercurial@XXXXX.XXXXX.com/repositories/XXXXX /home/XXXXX/mi-repo" /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TestRepo
abort: repository hg clone ssh://mercurial@XXXXX.XXXXX.com/repositories/XXXXX /home/XXXXX/mi-repo not found
ERROR: Failed to clone hg clone ssh://mercurial@XXXXX.XXXXX.com/repositories/XXXXX /home/XXXXX/mi-repo
ERROR: Failed to clone hg clone ssh://mercurial@XXXXX.XXXXX.com/repositories/XXXXX /home/XXXXX/mi-repo
Finished: FAILURE
```

I understand that I have a problem with my key verification, so I understand that I must not have it properly configured in Jenkins.

Any explanatory and eye-opening help would be very welcome.

Comment: The 4th line does not look like valid syntax. It has a second `hg clone` in double quotes?